# What is the difference between these winfo commands? (Tcl/Tk)

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, window-managers

What is the difference between the

```
winfo height *window*
winfo width *window*
```

commands and the

```
winfo screenheight *window*
winfo screenwidth *window*
```

commands?

Having read the documentation here: [Tk Built-In Commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M36)
, it seems to me like there is no difference in their return values. If so, what is the reason for the existence of these seemingly identical commands, historically?

Comment: The window and the window's **screen** are not the same thing. Have you tried running them on a window of yours to see what they return?

Comment: Ah I tested it now, thanks. Sorry for posting such a question so quickly before testing!!

Comment: The other one to beware of is `winfo reqheight`, which is the _requested_ height; `winfo height` is the _observed_ height. These can differ (and if that's causing problems, consider scheduling the code in a `<Configure>` event…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to test:

```
strobel@suse131-intel:~> wish
% winfo height .
200
% winfo screenheight .       
1200
```

So one is window, one is screen.

P.S. you should not answer in a comment, the question can't be marked answered.